# Unable to scan elements from a file and directly put it in array

Tags: c, arrays

Why am I unable to scan the elements from a file with the following prog? I am able to scan for the elements using a while loop. However, i wanted to put the elements in a 2-D Array, that is the reason I tried to use the for loop instead. Unfortunately, I am just not able to do it. Is there any particular reason for this, or am I doing something wrong.
Screen Shot of the error given below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ROW 3
#define COLUMN 12
#define SIZE 40
int main ()
{
int i ,j;
float sale[ROW][COLUMN];
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("store.txt", "r");
if(fp == NULL)
{
    printf("Error Opening File\n");
    return 0;
}
for(i=0; i<ROW; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<COLUMN; j++)
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%.2f", &sale[i][j]);
        printf("%.2f  ", sale[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```

Elements are

A  20000  15000  14000  14900  17800   12000   11500  11000  15700  18500 20400  31000
B  31900  17000  16700  17800  18800   22000   10500  11000  15890  17640 21750  32540

c  29000  17500  16600  14678  17970   12125   11576  12198  16700  19500 21400  31000

[image: Scree Shot of the Error]

Comment: Next time you can copy&paste the output of that Windows' console. Just right-click on the title of the console to see the option to make selections, then select the text and finish by right-clicking the text. That copies the text to your clipboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is this statement.

```
fscanf(fp, "%.2f", &sale[i][j]);
```

In fsanf format %.2f is invalid.In printf is OK.
In addition, you need to read the first char element，otherwise,can not read successful.
You can do it like this.

```
char buf[ROW];//for A B C
for(i=0,fscanf(fp,"%c",&buf[i]); i<ROW; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<COLUMN; j++)
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%f", &sale[i][j]);
        printf("%.2f", sale[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must not use `%Ld`, it is invalid. You should use either `%ld` for a `long int` or `%Lf` for a `long double`.

See here the complete table showing valid combinations: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Also, remember to check the return value of your functions, specially here `fscanf` can fail without you noticing.

Also consider initializing your `sale` array. The output you show is due to uninitialized memory.

Comment: I tried all that, still unsuccessful in scanning. Do you see any other logical mistakes in it.

Comment: Please update your code with the changes so we can see what you have now. Also, can you show the output, if any?

Comment: Just included the screen shot. and the dummy elements in files i am using.

Comment: After your modifications you put this in your `fscanf`: `%.2f`. Replace that to just `%f`. Also, in your file you have some letters at the beginning of each line, I removed the letters and your code works fine.

Comment: That really helps, However, can you let me know, why is it unable to scan with letters infront.

Comment: Because you are telling `fscanf` to read a `float` from the file but it reads `A`, which is not a `float` (so it doesn't assign anything and you see uninitialized memory when you use `printf`). Next time you call `fscanf` it sees the same `A` again so it fails once more. And so on. Do not forget to check your `fscanf` return value as that would tell you if it found invalid data to parse. If you need that letter in front, read it first with `%c`.

Comment: Is there any way to read a combination of strings and numbers?

Comment: you can specify several formats in `fscanf`, for example: `"%c %f %f %f %f"`, or you can just make separate calls to that function.